UWP can't play TTS stream
folks, I am writing a UWP in c# for a kiosk scenario. I am stumbled by TTS. here is my code, very simple, but no sound heard, no error reported:
using System;
using Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis;
using Windows.Media.Playback;
using Windows.Media.Core;

namespace UWPClient
{
    internal class Speaker
    {
        public async void Speak(string text )
        {
            var synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
            var stream = await synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync("hello");
            var player = new MediaPlayer();
            player.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromStream(stream, stream.ContentType);
            player.Play();
        }
    }
}

I have required "background media playback", "microphone", and even "Videos library" capabilities.
I've tried using MediaElement to play TTS stream following microsoft's example, however the symptom is the same as mediaplayer.

I tried your code in a blank project, the code works on my side. Have you tried to test it on a normal device in a new project? Would you mind share the code about where and how you call this method?

Thanks, Roy. It seems to be related to trust. I have built up trust between server and client devices using certificates and then It works partially. Why do I say "partially", because it works on a windows 11 client device but not on another windows 10 client device and both devices own same trust-links.  Addtionally, I have encountered lots of debugging challeges with UWP and I am however not so familiar with UWP.  So, I have now turned to WPF desktop clickonce solution. So far WPF desktop shows far more robust. However, I have to sacrifice Kiosk mode which just works for UWP.
